# Every star countable meta-Lindelöf space is Lindelöf.

Tags: general-topology

How could I prove this theorem:

> Every star countable meta-Lindelöf space is Lindelöf.

A space is meta-Lindelöf if every open cover has
a point-countable open refinement.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be star countable and metaLindelöf, and let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $X$. Let $\mathscr{V}$ be a point-countable open refinement of $\mathscr{U}$. Since $X$ is star countable, there is a countable $K\subseteq X$ such that $\mbox{St}(K,\mathscr{V})=X$. Let $\mathscr{V}_0=\{V\in\mathscr{V}:V\cap K\ne\varnothing\}$; each point of $K$ is in countably many members of $\mathscr{V}$, and $K$ is countable, so $\mathscr{V}_0$ is a countable open refinement of $\mathscr{U}$. For each $V\in\mathscr{V}$ choose $U_V\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $V\subseteq U_V$; then $\{U_V:V\in\mathscr{V}\}$ is a countable subcover of $\mathscr{U}$, and $X$ is Lindelöf.